# Twitter4j not returning any results on Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

Since Twitter moved to API v1.1, I've tried switching to Twitter4j to perform my queries. I've set up my dev account on twitter and I'm pretty sure I've set up OAuth ok:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("XXX")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("XXX")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXX");
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
System.setProperty("twitter4j.debug", "true");

try
{
    String url = "q=%40twitterapi%20-via";
    Query query = new Query(url);
    QueryResult result;
    do
    {
        result = twitter.search(query);                 

        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets)
        {
            results.add(getInfoFromTweet(tweet));
        }
    } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);

} catch (TwitterException te)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Problem gettibng results from twitter: " + url, te);
}
```

The main problem is that I never get any tweets returned in the results, though results itself seems rasonably well formed as far as I can see. The query string I'm using certainly seems to give plenty of results when I try it directly in a web browser: https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q=%40twitterapi%20-via

The other thing is that I can't work out how to get the debugging output from Twitter4j in Android. I've tried everything that I can find to get the debug output, but it's either not coming out or I'm not looking in the right place!

Comment: Same Problem. It looks like the underlying library is using API 1 for this call. Furthermore there are new methods associated with it in the API documentation.